# zend, i cant call any view helpers

Tags: zend-framework

i have a got a helpers folder in my views folder with a helper called Log.php
/views/helpers/log.php

which contains:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Log extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract 
{
    public function loggedAs ()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $username = $auth->getIdentity()->uname;
            $logoutUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller'=>'auth', 'action'=>'logout'), null, true);
            return 'Hello' . $username .  '. <a href="'.$logouturl.'">Logout?</a>';
        } 


    }
}
```

how can i call this from layouts? or views?  i tried $this->_helpers->log->loggedAs();

but doesnt display anything, just an error:Fatal error: Call to a member function loggedAs() on a non-object in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little experience in ZF. Yesterday I have the same problem and I decided its with the following code.
In the main Bootstrap.php I defined helper Path and Prefix

```
protected function _initDoctype()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/My/Helper/View", "My_Helper_View");
}
```

After that in view file I used next syntax

```
$this->getPhoneString($value['per_telephone_number']);
```

where **getPhoneString** method in my Helper Class **My_Helper_View_GetPhoneString**

Hope this example will be useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your helper class should have a method that matches the name of the helper, and this is what you call. So if you want to call `loggedAs()` from your templates then this is what you should name your helper:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_LoggedAs extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract 
{
    public function loggedAs()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $username = $auth->getIdentity()->uname;
            $logoutUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller'=>'auth', 'action'=>'logout'), null, true);
            return 'Hello' . $username .  '. <a href="'.$logouturl.'">Logout?</a>';
        } 
    }
}
```

this should then live in a file at `application/views/helpers/LoggedAs.php`, and you'd call it from within your templates like this:

```
<?=$this->loggedAs()?>
```

I'd also recommend using your own namespace instead of Zend in the class name, but the way you've done it should work as well.

Comment: tried this,, im getting: Plugin by name 'LoggedAs' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper